# What status ailment (or other) is the green feather/wing and how can I deal with it?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

I was grinding rages and APs in the Veldt when this happened:

[image: Gau has a green feather where his "job description" should be.]

I gave him a remedy, but the game didn't want any of it. Remedies are supposed to cure all but Zombie and KO, so I tried some Holy Water next - to no avail. Perhaps unsurprisingly, Phoenix Down also can't be used on Gau.

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The green feather indicates ["Float"](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Float_%28Status%29) status.

The reason that your Remedy didn't cure it is because it's considered a positive status by the game, not a negative one. The primary thing that Float status does is make Earth-elemental spells miss.

[Per the wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Float_%28Status%29#Final_Fantasy_VI), the list of abilities that Float will protect against is:

- Quake
- Midgardsormr
- Wombat
- Boar Brigade
- Chocobo Stampede
- Magnitude 8
- Land Slide
- Interceptor's Takedown
- Interceptor's Wild Fang

Comment: I guess I got that for free after using a Satellite rage.

Comment: I was confused with this same thing. I guess I got it for free after using a Bomb rage.